# What is the most elegant or conventional way to throw exceptions in a class implementing a generic interface?

Tags: java, generics, exception, polymorphism

I prefer to code against interfaces as a general rule. I tend to also use generic interfaces quite a bit. Coding against generic interfaces gives me the loosest coupling possible as my implementing classes may deal with different versions/variants of domain objects.

To cut to the chase:

- I prefer programming against interfaces to reduce coupling & to make testing easier
- I prefer to use generic interfaces and polymorphism to maximise implementation possibilities while maintaining API contract
- Generic interfaces can lead to the need for multiple generic types to handle potential concrete exception throws in implementing classes; it is v difficult to know ahead of time *how many* exceptions an interface method should throw
- I could eliminate method exception throwing with try-catch blocks in every relevant implementation, however, this would likely lead to *some* methods being messier than they ought to be

**There are probably some trade-offs here, but as a *general* rule, what is the best way to handle method throws exceptions in generic interfaces?**

Maybe there is not a one-size-fits-all answer - however, I would prefer my code to be as consistent as possible and my methods to be as small and self-documenting as possible.

Code example:

```
public interface IFooBarDoer<T1 extends Throwable, T2 extends Throwable, T3 extends Throwable, T4 extends Throwable> {
    String doSomethingWithFoo() throws T1, T2;
    String doSomethingWithBar() throws T3, T4;
}
import java.io.IOException;

public class FooBarDoerImpl implements IFooBarDoer {

    private final int id;
    private Foo foo;
    private Bar bar;

    public FooBarDoerImpl(int id, Foo foo, Bar bar) {
        this.id = id;
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public String doSomethingWithFoo() throws Exception, RuntimeException {
        /*
         do something exciting with this.foo
         that can lead to an exception.
        */
        return this.foo.getContents();
    }

    @Override
    public String doSomethingWithBar() throws NullPointerException, IOException {
        /*
         do something exciting with a bar
         that can lead to an error.
        */
        return this.foo.getContents();
    }
}

public class Foo {
    private final int id;
    private final String contents;

    public Foo(int id, String contents) {
        this.id = id;
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return this.contents;
    }
}

public class Bar {
    private final int id;
    private final String contents;

    public Bar(int id, String contents) {
        this.id = id;
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return this.contents;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you write some code to illustrate what you describe in words. A concrete example will help us better understand the general concepts that you are asking about.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice have now included a code example.